# Heating tag is only for space-heating or not?

Tags: discussion, tags

Almost all questions with the tag [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating) are about heating a space (e.g. your home), but in [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2888/99) the tag is used for heating food, as in [cooking](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking).

What do you think? Should we use the heating tag only for space heating? In that case we should probably merge [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating) with [space-heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-heating).

Or do we use heating as one broad category for alls kinds of heating. In this case the tags [space-heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-heating), [water-heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-heating) and [cooking](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) would remain as specific types of heating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest making [space-heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-heating) a synonym of [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating).

I find [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating) a more natural choice and don't think users will look for [space-heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-heating). (If they do, they'd be redirected to [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating).)

Moreover, [Wikipedia writes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_heater) that

> **Space heating** is generally employed to warm a small space, and **is usually held in contrast with central heating**, which warms many connected spaces at once. <sub><sup>(emphasis mine)</sup></sub>

I think that [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating), encompassing both space heating and central heating, is the better tag.

(In the sustainability context, [heating](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating) makes little sense for heating food, but a tag wiki should clarify this. For heating food, [food](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [cooking](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) should be more than enough.)

Comment: I've made both space-heating and heat a synonym of heating

Answer (score 1):

I find it odd to use the heating tag for cooking. We could make it a synonym of space-heating.